# Transitions and Transforms on the same Element, triggered by different Parents

Tags: html, css

I'm having a UL, LI with Links in it.

There is also an Arrow-Circle on the right side of the LI. It will be a subnavigation later.

---

I want the Arrow to grow (which works), when hovering the LI and to rotate (which works only a bit) when hovering the Arrow itself.

Unfortunately, only the growing is triggered, when hovering the LI and moving on to the Arrow. When hovering the Arrow directly, the rotation is triggered. So I'm sure the CSS Attribute is right, but the combination somehow isn't.

This is the relevant code:

```
li:hover .arrow {
  transition : 0.3s linear;
  transform : scale( 1.5 );
}
.arrow-wrap:hover .arrow {
  transition : 0.6s linear;
  transform : rotate(360deg);
}
```

To see a mockup-html version, visit this jsFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/csf3wwjn/1/

Can anyone tell, whe the rotate isn't triggered when first moving over the LI? I'm not very into the whole CSS3 animation thing and I didn't even know what to search for.

Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second transformation rule is overriding the first, you should define the scale rule together with the rotate one

```
/* interesting css */
li:hover .arrow {
  transition : 0.3s linear;
  transform: scale( 1.5 ) rotate(0deg);
}
.arrow-wrap:hover .arrow {
  transition : 0.6s linear;
  transform: scale( 1.5 ) rotate(360deg);
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/csf3wwjn/5/

Or, as @Harry pointed out, you can rotate the `.arrow-wrap` element

```
/* interesting css */
li:hover .arrow {
  transition : 0.3s linear;
  transform: scale( 1.5 );
}
.arrow-wrap:hover {
  transition : 0.6s linear;
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/csf3wwjn/6/

Comment: Oh, I tried this the first time. But all it does - when moving from grey to yellow - is, that the arrow gets blurry and doesn't move. Might it be a chrome issue? Will try other browsers.

Comment: It's not working in my FF either... When placing your mouse on top of the gray area, it grows right?

And then moving over to the yellow circle... Does it rotate?

Comment: @abidibo: I can see what Boris means. Try hovering the `li` first and then move directly from within the `li` to the `.arrow-wrap`. I see it both on Chrome and FF.

Comment: You! I like you! Thanks, that's exactly what I wanted :)

Comment: @Boris: If for whatever reason you don't want to add the `scale(1.5)` to the other `transform` setting also then you could do something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/csf3wwjn/6/) (rotate the wrapper). abidibo, feel free to add that to your answer if you wish to.